# How to make particular fields into separate columns?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot, plsqldeveloper

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

I have this table in the below format:

```
No | User | Value
01 | Port | Funds   
01 | Vip1 | Systems  
02 | Port | Bank  
02 | Vip1 | Authority
```

This is how I want it:

```
No | Port  | Vip1
01 | Funds | Systems   
02 | Bank  | Authority
```

Now the problem is, in this table, the User column has 6 other entries besides Port and Vip1. So I would want 6 columns and their respective values. I also want a query that I can use in other similar tables that have different User column entries. This is what I was trying to do without any success:

```
SELECT 
   No, 
   CASE user WHEN 'Port' THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS Port,  
   CASE user WHEN 'Vip1' THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS Vip1  
FROM table1
```

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: We think you should show us, what you tried, first.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are having while trying to resolve this problem, or are you just asking us to do your work for you?

Comment: Such tasks are normally solved with **PIVOT** [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html], however if you need to have a variable number of columns, you'll have to use **dynamic query** [http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:447101300034625723] and/or **PIVOT XML** [http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506]

Comment: `USER` is a builtin function. You will want to avoid using keywords and builtin functions as column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  What you need is aggregation:

```
SELECT 
   No, 
   max(CASE user WHEN 'Port' THEN Value END) AS Port,  
   max(CASE user WHEN 'Vip1' THEN Value END) AS Vip1  
FROM table1
group by No;
```

I also removed the `else NULL`.  By default, the `case` statement returns `NULL` when there is no match.

EDIT:

Actually, in Oracle, you can do something.  But, you only have generic names (unless you use dynamic SQL):

```
select no,
       max(case when usernum = 1 then value end) as Val1,
       max(case when usernum = 2 then value end) as Val2,
       max(case when usernum = 3 then value end) as Val3,
       max(case when usernum = 4 then value end) as Val4,
       max(case when usernum = 5 then value end) as Val5,
       max(case when usernum = 6 then value end) as Val6,
       max(case when usernum = 1 then user end) as User1,
       max(case when usernum = 2 then user end) as User2,
       max(case when usernum = 3 then user end) as User3,
       max(case when usernum = 4 then user end) as User4,
       max(case when usernum = 5 then user end) as User5,
       max(case when usernum = 6 then user end) as User6
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by user) as usernum
      from table1 t
     ) t
group by No;
```

This returns 6 columns with the value and 6 more columns with the name.  This may not be exactly what you are looking for.  But, without dynamic SQL it is possibly the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But what if the fields in the User column are unknown? I can only use case if I know the fields would be either Port or Vip1. What if there are 5 others?

Comment: I tried using this but it gives me all the value column's fields in Val1 and all the User column fields in User1 while the rest of the columns are empty. Also i have never used dynamic SQL, could you please point me to the right direction regarding using these,

Comment: @user2607095 . . . I think I fixed that problem.